# How to use regex to capture the correct repeated group?

Tags: python, regex

A html containing 2 lines far apart from each other like below. Please note that there are 2 identical strings at the beginning of these two lines.

```
<a href="http://example.com">file 1</a><a href="http://example.com/right2">file 2</a><a href="http://example.com/right3">file 3</a>

<a href="http://example.com">file 1</a><a href="http://example.com/left2">file 2</a><a href="http://example.com/left3">file 3</a>
```

I'd like regex to give me only the result from the first line above, which is

```
http://example.com
http://example.com/right2
http://example.com/right3

file 1
file 2
file 3
```

If I use this regular expression

```
re.compile('<a href="(.+?)">(.+?)</a>').findall()
```

Then I have

```
http://example.com
http://example.com/right2
http://example.com/right3
http://example.com
http://example.com/left2
http://example.com/left3

file 1
file 2
file 3
file 1
file 2
file 3
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I am a newbie and still need to learn a lot more about regex. Beautiful Soup is one of my unknown territories, but I'll take a look later. Anyway, how can I do a quick fix on my regex above to get my result?

Comment: Why don't you try this regex http://regex101.com/r/kE0wF3/2 ?

Comment: So far you haven't shown what is variable/fixed from which to make a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Save the href values. Stop if you find duplicated attribute value:

```
>>> import re
>>> matches = re.findall('<a href="(.+?)">(.+?)</a>', html_string)
>>> seen = set()
>>> for href, text in matches:
...     if href in seen:
...         break
...     seen.add(href)
...     print('{} {}'.format(href, text))
...
http://example.com file 1
http://example.com/right2 file 2
http://example.com/right3 file 3
```

Using [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string)
seen = set()
for tag in soup.select('a[href]'):
    if tag['href'] in seen:
        break
    seen.add(tag['href'])
    print('{} {}'.format(tag['href'], tag.text))
```